# How to check array in fetch_array if its contain certain word?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hi I want to check if my `fetch_array` is contain some string that I want
here is the souce code

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT g.No_meja 
                                        FROM orders o JOIN guest_order gord ON o.Kode_Guest_Order = gord.Kode_guest_order JOIN guest g ON gord.Kode_Meja = g.Kode_meja
                                                                 JOIN product_order po ON o.Kode_Produk_Order = po.Kode_produk_order
                                                                 JOIN product p ON po.Kode_Produk = p.Kode_produk
                                                                 JOIN topping_order tord ON po.Kode_produk_order = tord.Kode_Produk_Order
                                                                 JOIN topping t ON tord.Kode_Topping = t.Kode_topping
                                        WHERE o.Status_order = 'Disiapkan' GROUP BY o.Kode_order;");
                $stmt->execute();
                $resultTableColor = $stmt -> get_result();
                while ($rowTable = $resultTableColor -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

                    if(strpos($rowTable['No_meja'],"1")){
                        $table1Status = "green";
                    }
                    else {
                        $table1Status = "white";
                    }
                    
                    if (strpos($rowTable['No_meja'],"2")){
                        
                        $table2Status = "green";
                        
                    }
                    else {
                        $table2Status = "white";
                        
                    }
                    if (strpos($rowTable['No_meja'],"9")){
                        $table9Status = "green";
                    }
                    else {
                        $table9Status = "white";
                    }  
                }
                echo "Table 1 ".$table1Status. "<br>";
                echo "Table 2 ".$table2Status."<br>";
                echo "Table 9 ".$table9Status."<br>";
```

Update :
the `strpos` is working but it always turn to false

The Output of the Query is like this :

[image: query]

the output should be green if its found its "certain number" but it always getting false so the output is white
[image: output]

Comment: In `strpos()` the haystack is before the needle. In other words you need to swap the arguments.

Comment: Yes, the repeating is because you put the echo within the loop, instead of after it; however, why are you doing this in PHP ? it's likely easier to just put a `WHERE` clause in your query.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware oh my god, didn't realized it that the argument is backward

Comment: @Raxi because I want to use it with many if else condition, and it would be cramped if ill do select with each table which is i have 13 tables

Comment: myea. i have no idea about your database layout of course. But generally SQL with its `WHERE` clause and `IN` operator and the like is best suited for these things.

Comment: @Raxi, Hmmm ill try that, thankss

Comment: Now the function always goes to false after finding the word

Comment: ill update the question

Comment: Why would you use `strpos` when it's a single integer you're evaluating there, `if($rowTable['No_meja'] == "2")` should suffice?

Comment: Really, this would suffice, additionally using a [ternary operator](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-ternary-operator/) in place of the `if/else` statements : `$table1Status = $rowTable['No_meja'] == 1 ? 'green' : 'white';
$table2Status = $rowTable['No_meja'] == 2 ? 'green' : 'white';
$table3Status = $rowTable['No_meja'] == 9 ? 'green' : 'white';`

Comment: @MarkusAO, because the `$rowTable['No_meja']` is array if I use the regular if else or the ternary it would be get the last of the array number that is `9` and will only return true in the function of `9`

Comment: There is no `array` datatype in SQL. Your sample data shows single integers there. Are you storing comma-separated values? (If so, [please read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70530609/how-to-solve-this-mysql-query-in-php-page) on the drawbacks.) At any rate, if you ever have numbers above 9, `strpos` would return a false positive for e.g. `strpos('12', '2')` etc. You'd be better off using `explode(',', $rowTable['No_meja'])` and `in_array()`, if you must have CSV.

Comment: No, I'm not using any comma-separated values, the output is pure integer like `2 2 9` as seen as the post screenshot. The tables (not the mysql table) is originally 13 tables, but in this case I'm only selected the table that ordered food, which is table 2 with 3 orders and table 9 with 1 orders. I tried to use `explode()` but still no success.

Comment: but im doing in separate file like doing to original array which is not from `fetch_array()`
with 
`$table = array("2", "2","2", "9");

if (stripos(json_encode($table),'2') !==FALSE){
    $table2Status = 'green'; 
}
else {
    $table2Status = "white";
}
echo $table2Status; 
`
its working perfect. 
when I tried to change with mysql output in my original code its still not working

Comment: Solved it! , 
instead doing each if else each tables, I'm doing it with one if else but with many clauses 

and changes the method from `strpos` to using the regular if else comparation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn Out I was wrong puting the strpos parameter it should be `strpos($rowTableColor['No_meja'],$table2Check)`

UPDATE :
thanks to [php if statement on mysqli fetch array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121856/php-if-statement-on-mysqli-fetch-array)

I'll be able to solve it

by changing the query by :

```
SELECT g.No_meja 
FROM orders o JOIN guest_order gord ON o.Kode_Guest_Order = gord.Kode_guest_order JOIN guest g ON gord.Kode_Meja = g.Kode_meja
              JOIN product_order po ON o.Kode_Produk_Order = po.Kode_produk_order
              JOIN product p ON po.Kode_Produk = p.Kode_produk
              JOIN topping_order tord ON po.Kode_produk_order = tord.Kode_Produk_Order
              JOIN topping t ON tord.Kode_Topping = t.Kode_topping
WHERE o.Status_order = 'Disiapkan' 
GROUP BY o.Kode_order ORDER BY gord.Kode_Guest_Order DESC;
```

and changing the method from `strpos` to regular if-else comparison like this :

```
while ($RowTable = $resultTableColor -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                        
                        if ($RowTable['No_meja'] == "1"){
                            $table1Status = "green";
                        }
                        else if($RowTable['No_meja'] == "2"){
                            $table2Status = "green";
                        }
                        else if ($RowTable['No_meja'] == "3"){
                            $table3Status = "green";
                        }
                        else if ($RowTable['No_meja'] == "4"){
                            $table4Status = "green";
                        }
                        else if ($RowTable['No_meja'] == "6"){
                            $table6Status = "green";
                        }
                        else if ($RowTable['No_meja'] == "7"){
                            $table7Status = "green";
                        }
                        else if ($RowTable['No_meja'] == "9"){
                            $table9Status = "green";
                        }
                        else if ($RowTable['No_meja'] == "10"){
                            $table10Status = "green";
                        }
                        else if ($RowTable['No_meja'] == "11"){
                            $table11Status = "green";
                        }
                        else if ($RowTable['No_meja'] == "12"){
                            $table12Status = "green";
                        }
                        else if ($RowTable['No_meja'] == "13"){
                            $table13Status = "green";
                        }
                        else {
                            
                        }
                    }
```

and set the default color that is `white` outside of `while` before the `query` :

```
$table1Status = "white";
$table2Status = "white";
$table3Status = "white";
$table4Status = "white";
$table6Status = "white";
$table7Status = "white";
$table9Status = "white";
$table10Status = "white";
$table11Status = "white";
$table12Status = "white";
$table13Status = "white";
```